# Complete silence on Lollipop

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.1-lollipop

Until KitKat I was able to silence a device completely by simply pressing volume-down. Repeat presses first reached "vibrate" and then "not even vibrate". This is very handy just before meetings/lectures/..

Now with Lollipop pressing all the way down reaches just "vibrate".

How do I recover the ability to completely silence Lollipop using the volume-down button?

I am aware of the power-saving widget, but I'd still like to sync while the device is silenced.

Comment: Enabling the 'do not disturb mode' silences all notifications and alarms. Press the volume down button and you'll see the 3 categories "None", "Priority" and "All" Notifications. Choose none should do the trick

Comment: "None" works for meetings/lectures/theaters/.., but is not suitable for sleeping. It also disables alarms. Thoughts?

Comment: I am using the priority notification mode over night which mutes all messages/calls but leaves the alarm as it is.

Comment: @benjaminS That makes sense. So really "None" should be interpreted/functions as "in a meeting", and "Priority" functions as "sleeping". The labels are somewhat machine-tilted rather than meant for humans, but they are sufficiently general in case, for instance, one still wants to be interrupted during a meeting or while sleeping.